# Posting status on Facebook via Easy Facebook SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I cant find way to post new status on Facebook via Easy Facebook SDK.
Im logging in, everythings is ok. Then trying to fire up this line of code

```
       Status facebookStatus;
       /* some code */
       facebookStatus.setMessage("Some text");
```

aaaand im getting force close dialog :S

Site: http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/

Reference: http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/doc/com/easy/facebook/android/data/Status.html#setMessage%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? Post your `logcat` output.

Comment: Does your logCat show anything?

Comment: logcat output only this, that there is a somethin wrong in facebookStatus.setMessage("Some text");

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you haven't created the `Status` object. If that's the case, then change the first line to:

```
Status facebookStatus = new Status();
```

Comment: But still there is no post on my wall/timeline :S

Comment: @Evelan: the information you provided was enough to solve the crash issue, but with two lines of code no more magic is possible, I'm affraid.

Comment: I see, but there is no more code associated with facebook status. Standard example code from site to login + this what I wrote.

Comment: @Evelan: the example could be broken. And your app config could be broken too. Does `lolcat` say anything interesting when you try to post the status?